# Replacing word on webpage while excluding tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am attempting to create a chrome extension that replaces all instances of a word.

So far, I've been using this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Word", "g"), "replacement");
```

and everything works, although it also replaces the text from some tags on the webpages, which ruins the websites CSS.

How would I go about ignoring the tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookaheads may work. If your "word" is a part of a tag, then, it would ultimately be followed by ">". So, by using a negative lookahead, you can skip those. This would be your regex -

```
/word(?![^<]*>)/g
```

Consider the "word" to be "head", and the replacement be "tail" for the string in this example-

```
> str = "<head> <title> And off with your head! and other head references. </title></ head>"
> str.replace(/head(?![^<]*>)/g, "tail")
//"<head> <title> And off with your tail! and other tail references. </title></ head>"
```

Notice that the `<head>` and `</head>` were not replaced.